# ImportError: No module named 'MySQL'

Tags: python, mysql

I have downloaded the Connector/Python for MySQL successfully. I used the following code in Python's shell to test my connection:

`import mysql.connector`

I received the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I can't figure out why MySQL is not being recognized.

Comment: Is python configured to be in your PATH environment variable?  I believe this is necessary for proper installation.

Comment: What platform are you on?  Windows?

Comment: OS X, I tested this in my shell: print(get_python_lib()) and it returned 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Comment: `print(sys.path)
['/Users/Noah/Desktop/Melanie', '/Users/Noah/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']`

Comment: Do you see the connector installed in that directory?  From your python shell, execute `os.listdir("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages")`.  And running `which python` in the terminal gives you that path as well?

Comment: I recieved the following error when running the above: 
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site\u200c\u200b-packages'`

Comment: you have to change your file name `mysql`

Comment: Just run pip install mysql-connector

Answer (score 178):

I was facing the similar issue. My env details -
Python 2.7.11
pip 9.0.1
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)

Error on python interpreter -

```
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
>>>
```

Use pip to search the available module -

```
$ pip search mysql-connector | grep --color mysql-connector-python



mysql-connector-python-rf (2.2.2)        - MySQL driver written in Python
mysql-connector-python (2.0.4)           - MySQL driver written in Python
```

Install the mysql-connector-python-rf -

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Verify

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Apr 26 2016, 13:18:56)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```

Thanks =)

For python3 and later use the next command:
$ pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf

Comment: `pip install mysql-connector` was enough for me.

Comment: Also, don't call your python script **"mysql.py"**. Just in case.

Comment: Just in case anyone is as dumb as me, for me an additional step was needed. After following the advice in this answer I needed to select the right Python interpreter in PyCharm run configuration (the one within the venv I installed all modules to).

Comment: thank you. pip search mysql-connector This is really useful

Comment: `pip3 install mysql-connector-python`

Comment: Well, this worked.
but how is rf different from other version!?

Comment: In the python shell `>>> import mysql.connector` no longer gives an error, but using `import mysql.connector` in a python module still gives that same error (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'`).

Comment: OMG @Benji I feel so stupid now... (quickly renamed `python.py`). Thanks for showing me my stupidity

Answer (score 65):

Use 
`pip3 install mysql-connector`
to install the python packaged (if you are using Python 3. For Python 2 you can use `pip`).

Comment: It is not working, pip install mysql-connector-python is working

Answer (score 43):

The silly mistake I had done was keeping `mysql.py` in same dir. Try renaming `mysql.py` to another name so `python` don't consider that as module.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Comment: I had the same error. i'm voting for this answer because this is what was happening to me. my script as named mysql.py and aparently it's not permitted. I changed to conecta.py and it worked.

Comment: Damn! This should be the accepted answer! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem, please don't use your file name mysql.py

Comment: This worked for me after trying all before solutions. Thx

Answer (score 37):

May be simple install from cli?

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Package name differs from import library name

Or my universal variant in code:

```py
import pip
pip.main(['install','mysql-connector-python-rf'])
```

For new version of pip:

```py
from pip._internal import main
main(['install','mysql-connector-python-rf'])
```

It's better - install needed modules in running python installation (if many)

Comment: This gives me a long, red and scary error. @ilexcel's answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 37):

I tried all the answers but not worked for me.
It is a python version problem, in the end, I realized that python 3 scripts need explicit pip command for python 3, at least on ubuntu 18.

```
python3 -m pip install mysql-connector
```

Answer (score 5):

Try that out bud

```
sudo wget http://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz

gunzip mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz

tar xf mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar

cd mysql-connector-python-2.1.3

sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use anaconda to manage python environment dependencies. MySQL connector can be installed using conda installer

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: Anaconda is well  accepted Python dependency manager. Please comment if it is not true.

Answer (score 5):

run

```py
pip list
```

to see list of packages you have installed. If it has
`mysql-connector-python` then that is fine.

Remember not to name your python script file as mysql.py

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Great help ! I had everything correct but my script file was named as "mysql.py".

Answer (score 4):

###### ️ in a virtual environment or using Python 2

pip install mysql-connector-python

###### ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

pip3 install mysql-connector-python

###### ️ if you get permissions error

sudo pip3 install mysql-connector-python
pip install mysql-connector-python --user

###### ️ if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable

python -m pip install mysql-connector-python

###### ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python

###### ️ using py alias (Windows)

py -m pip install mysql-connector-python

###### ️ for Anaconda

conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python

###### ️ for Jupyter Notebook

!pip install mysql-connector-python

Source: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-mysql

Answer (score 3):

just a note, I just installed mysql on an ubuntu 16.04 server. I tried different options in the following order:

- using the package from repository `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`: Was installed correctly, but unfortunatelly python returned `ImportError: No module named 'mysql'`
- using the ubuntu package from Mysql: `wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python_2.1.4-1ubuntu16.04_all.deb`. Installed correctly with `sudo dpckg -i package_name`, but python returned the same error.
- using tar.gz file, installing with python, worked ok.

  - `wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.6.tar.gz` (used 2.1.4 at that time)
  - `tar -xf mysql-connector-python-2.1.6.tar.gz`
  - `cd mysql-connector-python-2.1.6/`
  - `sudo python3 setup.py install`

Did not investigate why the first two failed, might try later. 
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Cristian - thanks for this, can you elaborate on the solution (I believe the tar.gz file) that worked for you?  I'm having the same issue, but your third option is short on detail.  Thank you!

Comment: sorry, I just read your comment now. 
I left the workplace where I did this. Did a quick test on a VM which seemed to work, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

This problem was a plague to me!!! The 100% solution is to forget using the mysql module: **`import mysql.connector`**, instead use [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/) via import pymysql. I installed it via the instructions: python3 -m pip install PyMySQL

made a change to the:

1. Import statement
2. The connector
3. The cursor

After that everything worked like a charm. Hope this helps!

Comment: can you please list the changes that you made?

Comment: I was stuck with OpenSUSE Leap. This is a very quick and safe workaround. Worked from me.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been fighting with mysql.connector for 48 hours.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue on mac and linux both despite installing the connector using the command as mentioned in the other answers.
What worked for me the following commands.

```
sudo python3 -m ensurepip --default-pip
python3 -m pip --version
sudo python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```

I don't know what difference do they make since I am not a python programmer but would like to know if someone can enlighten.

Answer (score 2):

I found that @gdxn96 solution worked for me, but with 1 change.

```
sudo wget http://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz
tar -zxvf mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar
cd mysql-connector-python-2.1.3
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found another reason: 
If your program file's path contains space or special characters, then you'd get this error.

Answer (score 1):

@nembokid
Thanks, I wanted to build on this answer. If you're using anaconda or any other form of environment management, be sure to select the python from that environment.

```
sudo /home/joseph/anaconda3/envs/stocks/bin/python -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue I resolved it using the following steps:
Step 1 - in terminal type echo %path% look for a file that's similar "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39"
Step 2 - in vs code type "ctrl+shift+p" select python interpreter
Step 3 - make sure you select the interpreter with the correct path, you found yours when you used echo %path%

Now run the program !

Answer (score 1):

in my case - for python 3.x  works

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue, search a lot but didn't found any useful answer. Finally I found a mistake that first you should check your script name. Your script name shouldn't be mysql.py.

Comment: That is already covered in the answer by Deepak Chauhan; maybe delete yours and upvote that answer instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the following commands. Which one depends on different-2 OS and software you have and use.

```
sudo easy_install mysql-python (mix os)
sudo pip install mysql-python (mix os)
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb (Linux Ubuntu, ...)
cd /usr/ports/databases/py-MySQLdb && make install clean (FreeBSD)
yum install MySQL-python (Linux Fedora, CentOS ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just moved source folder `connector` from folder `mysql` to `site-packages`.
And run `import connector`

Answer (score 0):

For 64-bit windows

install using wheel

```
pip install wheel download from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python
```

For python 3.x:

```
pip install mysqlclient-xxxxxxxxx-win_amd64.whl
```

For python 2.7:

```
pip install mysqlclient-xxxxxxxxx-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Where do you find the versions?

Answer (score 0):

My project was using `pipenv`. The following command worked for me:

```
pipenv install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I did try re-install with apt and pip.
But the only thing that worked was [install from source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-source.html).

On Ubuntu 18.04 x64

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed the issue on my end.

**Issue**
I couldn't neither compile nor have the package available on VSCode.

**Context**
System: Ubuntu 18.04
Python version: 3.6.*
**Installed Packages**

1. mysql
2. mysql-connector-python
3. mysql-connector-python-rf

**How I solved:**
Nothing really worked until I see this article:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext-development.html

On python console, just set

```
use_pure = True
```

With that, I could use python based connector instead.

```py
import mysql.connector
```

However, if something goes wrong, the C Extension can be used through the _mysql_connector module.

**References:**

1. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext-module.html
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/a0q4bq/mysqlconnector_how_to_use_use_puretrue/
3. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html
4. https://overiq.com/mysql-connector-python-101/installing-mysql-connector-python/

Answer (score 0):

My project was using windows+pipenv+vscode.
I had to activate the virtualenv via prompt and then open my project

```
pipenv shell
code .
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and it's just you need to change the file name I use `mysql.py` and I change it to same things ales and it's work fine