# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' even when module is installed

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to write a script that would read and write to a mysql table. I have installed mysql-connector on python3 and I got the script working yesterday. It successfully read and wrote data to mysql. When I ran it today, this error came up. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

I already checked the following things:

- mysql-connector is installed
- I don't have any user-defined module named mysql
- not running on virtualenv

Does someone have any idea on what is happening?

Comment: Ensure `mysql` is installed to the correct Python3. If you do `python3 -m pip freeze` you should see what packages are installed -- if you need to install it, simply do `python3 -m pip install mysql`.

Comment: I only have the one python3 installed. ```python3 -m pip freeze``` gives me this: mysql-connector-python==8.0.19 @Felipe. So I believe I have it installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

check if mysql-connector is installed: python -m pip freeze. It is probably not listed. You can install it with:

> pip install mysql-connector

or

> python -m pip install mysql-connector

Comment: please also see [import-error-no-module-named-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql)