# mysql connector not found

Tags: python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I am using Python3, I have tried to install mysql.connector with this command

`pip install mysql-connector-python-rf`

but when I run the code I get **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'**

if I tipe in `pip search mysql-connector-python` it founds this versions:

```
mysql-connector-python (8.0.20)               - MySQL driver written in Python
  INSTALLED: 8.0.20 (latest)
mysql-connector (2.2.9)                       - MySQL driver written in Python
beam-mysql-connector (1.8.2)                  - MySQL I/O Connector of Apache Beam
mysql-connector-python-dd (2.0.2)             - MySQL driver written in Python
  INSTALLED: 2.0.2 (latest)
mysql-connector-python-rf (2.2.2)             - MySQL driver written in Python
  INSTALLED: 2.2.2 (latest)
MySQL-python (1.2.5)                          - Python interface to MySQL
mysql-connector-repackaged (0.3.1)            - MySQL driver written in Python
```

What am I missing ??

Comment: The `-rf` module is probably not the one you want. Try installing with `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Comment: If on python3, you can use `python3-mysql.connector`, more on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to install multiple versions of mysql-connector, however, I have found the problem. I had to *change the configuration* and **set the interpreter to its default location** and install mysql-connector once again with `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Answer (score 0):

The official MySQL Connector/Python in PyPI is `mysql-connector-python`. So `pip install mysql-connector-python` is the way to go.