# I have pip installed requests however I am getting this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: path

I am using python version 3.8.
I am using the most recent version of Atom which is the text editor I am running my file.
I am just running import requests.
Python is downloaded directly on my C drive and it is throwing out this error.
File "C:\Users\Admin\github\WolfPackTwitterBot\weather.py", line 1, in 
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two or more installed exemplars of Python, you need specify full path to pip.exe

Or use a crutch from [my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql/44016138#44016138):

```
from pip._internal import main
main(['install','requests'])
```

It runs in current python instance, which need to install