# Updated to Python 3.9.1 (64bit) from 3.8 32 bit. Now I can't get MySQL code to work

Tags: python, mysql, windows-10-universal

I hope this is what I am supposed to do.....
Below is the history

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.685]

C:\Users\JK>pip list
Package         Version
--------------- -------
click           7.1.2
Flask           1.1.2
Flask-MySQL     1.5.1
itsdangerous    1.1.0
Jinja2          2.11.2
MarkupSafe      1.1.1
mysql           0.0.2
mysql-connector 2.2.9
mysqlclient     2.0.2
pip             20.3.3
PyMySQL         0.10.1
setuptools      49.2.1
Werkzeug        1.0.1

C:\Users\JK>python 
3.9.1 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I tried various suggestions (of what to install) with pip in this thread to no avail. [ImportError: No module named 'MySQL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql)

The PyCharm error:
(<class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'mysql'")

I tried the original python code to access mysql first I had working under 3.8 32 bit.

snipit-1:

```
    import mysql.connector <---- gave me a similar error
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="****",
    database='db_name'
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

snipit-2 <---- this comes from a tutorial I found last night from 2019.

```
    from flask import MySQL <----- this gave the error
    mysql = MySQL()
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '*****'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'db_name'
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    mysql.init_app(app)
    mysql_connection =  mysql.connect()
    mycursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
```

Comment: You "tried various suggestions in" _which_ thread? That would help. When you change from 32 to 64 bit other configuration issues can arise.

Comment: This Thread.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql

Comment: There seems to be many ways to access MySQL. But it's hard to tell the "correct way" when upgrading.

Comment: You can make the edits to your post directly to improve readability. Please take a look at the formatting @venky__ did to improve your post.

Comment: I saw that. Thanks Perter K  and venky for the newbe instructions. I will assume that you are suggesting I remove the two comments, edit the original post and format them there. Working on it.

Comment: when you change Python version then you have to install all modules again - because Python versions have modules created only for own version - and especially when you change 32bit to 64bit. And it may needs to install C/C++ library for MySQL in 64bit version too. And every Python have own version of `pip` so you could also check `python -m pip list` instead of `pip list` to make sure you run `pip` for new version (you can also check `pip -V` and `python -V` to see versions)

Comment: Thanks @furas, I did try to do exactly as you suggest (install the various modules). I ju20.3.3 t checked the versions and indeed it is python 3.9.1, pip from ...\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9 and rerunning python -m pip list I get the identical list.

Comment: I am wondering why I would need all these:
mysql           0.0.2
mysql-connector 2.2.9
mysqlclient     2.0.2
PyMySQL         0.10.1
Or if I am missing a module I need.

Comment: everyone can write module and people created many modules to work with MySQL - but you don't need all of them. You can choose one module which you like and which works on your computer. I preferre `mysql-connector` because it is created by authors of database `MySQL` (you can find it on mysql.com) so it should be always fresh.

Comment: BTW: you checked `Python` in console but I see you use `PyCharm` which may have installed own Python and you may have to check modules installed in this version. `PyCharm` has somewhere in settings function to install modules for version which it uses. OR in settings you should set your Python as default in PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks @furas! I found that out after I installed python and removed/uninstalled and deleted the python 3.8 version. Pycharm couldn't find it. So I read more about it and in settings>python interpreter pointed it to the newly installed python 3.9. I had just installed the module mysql-connector. I am going to give that a shot now.

Comment: Resolved. I didn't understand how PyCharm worked well enough to know how to use global site packages.

Comment: Just installing MySQL 8.0 and found it says the Python connector works with 3.3, 3.5 ... 3.8 and won't accept 3.9 as satisfying the dependency. Irritating as I don't want to put old versions of python on the system if I can possibly help it.

This might explain some issues - and suggests these comments may be help in my trying to add it manually in after installation.

But this might be the underlying cause of a problem...