# Getting "ImportError: No module named 'MySQL'" and I don't know why

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

This issue has been bugging me for a while. So, I am using Python 3.9.10 on my Windows 10 computer. To install `mysql.connector`, I used this command in the command prompt:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

And, it returns this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in c:\users\aksha\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (8.0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.0.0 in c:\users\aksha\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from mysql-connector-python) (3.15.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in c:\users\aksha\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.0.0->mysql-connector-python) (1.15.0)
```

Next, I went to the python shell and entered this code:

```
import mysql.connector
```

And, got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I then went back to the command prompt and entered this command:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

This is what I get:

```
Using cached mysql-connector-2.2.9.tar.gz (11.9 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for mysql-connector, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mysql-connector
    Running setup.py install for mysql-connector ... done
Successfully installed mysql-connector-2.2.9
```

I go back to the python shell and enter the the same code, and it gives back the same error.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong and why this error keeps coming. I have already gone through posts like "[ImportError: No module named 'MySQL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql)", but I am still facing the same issue. I have also checked if I have any python scripts named `mysql.py` since I have heard they can cause some problems, but there aren't any.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit 1:
Just did `pip freeze` in the command prompt. This is the result:

```
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.24
protobuf==3.15.6
six==1.15.0
```

Not sure what to do now.

Comment: What IDE are you using?  It's possible your IDE is using a Python distribution separate from the one where you installed it.

Comment: I am using IDLE Shell 3.9.10. for anything code related for Python.

Comment: What do you get when you do a "pip freeze"? Do you see mysql module there?

Comment: So, I did just did a pip freeze on command prompt now. This is what I get: ```mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.24
protobuf==3.15.6
six==1.15.0 ```

Comment: Enter "import sys; sys.executable" in your python shell, what do you get?

Comment: So, this is what i got: ```'C:\\Users\\aksha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\pythonw.exe'```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

First run this command in the IDLE shell.

```
import sys; sys.executable
```

From this you'll get a python path like: `C:\\Users\\prat\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\pythonw.exe`

Then use this path with the pip install like:

```
entire_path -m pip install package-name
```

Comment: Hey! So, here's what I typed in the command prompt: ```C:\\Users\\aksha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\pythonw.exe -m pip install mysql-connector-python```. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah did it work?

Comment: Entered the command and checked whether it worked in IDLE using ```import mysql.connector```. The same error is still coming. Not sure why.