# No module named "mysql"

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection

I am connecting to MySql with Python, but when I am running the program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/SAM1.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I have referred a similar question on this error whose link is as follows:
[ImportError: No module named 'MySQL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql)

[image: This is the exact replication of what I did after seeing the answer given in the mentioned link]

but somehow things are not working out for me.
Here is the code:

```
print("Enter 1 to insert train records")
print("Enter 2 to update train records")
print("Enter 3 to delete train records")
print("Enter 4 to see all the records")
a=int(input("Enter the option"))
import mysql.connector
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="0000",database="test")
tracur=mydb.cursor()
tracur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TMS1(Train_no varchar(20) primary key,Train_name 
char(150),Departing_station char(100),Arriving_station char(100),Departing_time 
varchar(100),Arriving_time varchar(100))")

if a==1:
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="0000",database="test")
    tracur=mydb.cursor()
    b=input("Enter the Train Number: ")
    c=input("Enter the Train Name: ")
    d=input("Enter the Departing Station: ")
    e=input("Enter the Arriving Station: ")
    f=input("Enter the Departing Time: ")
    g=input("Enter the Arriving Time: ")
    tracur.execute("INSERT INTO 
TMS1(Train_no,Train_name,Departing_station,Arriving_station,Departing_time,Arriving_time)VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",(b,c,d,e,f,g))
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

It would be great if you could help me out with this code.

Comment: Having "referred" to that question, what did you then do to fix your problem?   The answers to that question list a whole lot of things that you could do / try.  What did you do?

Comment: FWIW, I can't see anything wrong with the code.  But for an error message like that, I wouldn't expect the problem to be in the code.  It seems to be saying that it can't find the `mysql` module in your installed python libraries.

Comment: Are you sure you have the mysql module installed in the environment you are using? That's the most likely cause I can think of. Meaning, you have for example installed it in a venv while your IDE doesn't use it or vice versa.

Comment: I have posted the image of what exactly I did after seeing the solution.

Comment: @Vulpex I will just try it on any other environment

Comment: I tried the above code in Spyder. An issue reporter is opening up and it says that spyder encountered an internal problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the necessary package using:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot but I have already done that and the cmd shows that the requirement is already satisfied

Comment: It is working now. I tried it once again. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. You can always reinstall broken packages using `pip install --upgrade mysql-connector-python`