# How to know which pip install command to run when requiments.txt is absent

Tags: python, pip

this fellow pythoneer had issues because his code had

```
import mysql.connector
```

and his lib wasn't getting recognized.

I had the same issue, so his question
([ImportError: No module named 'MySQL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql))
helped me a lot. (it solved the problem) But my question is:

How am I suposed to know that mysql.connector is installed via

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

and not a simple *pip instal mysql* that suposedely would install everything and my python code would find the *connector* sub-lib inside *mysql* lib ?

usually when we learn how imports work, we learn that if you have

```
import library.sublibrary
```

if you already have *library* installed, it would work. So why is it an exception ?
What am I missing ?

thanks.

Comment: The naming between the package on pip and its name in code is arbitrary; most packages are simply named the same in both cases, but that's not a must. What to do when a requirements.txt is missing is to [Find The Previous Dev And Kill Them](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0936501/); and then perhaps to do some googling to find the right package.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758